# Is adding 2D basis random vectors the same as adding two random variables?

Tags: probability

I'm trying to understand if the addition of random vectors leads to the same outcome as adding random variables.

Suppose $X \sim f$ is some random variable with some distribution $f$ and suppose $X$ has an expectation $\Bbb  E[X]$. Suppose there is another variable $Y$ with the same distribution.

Suppose there is some random vector $\mathbf{A} = (a_1,...,a_n)$ where, $\forall i$ , each $a_i \sim f$. Suppose there's a random vector $\mathbf{B}$ with the same properties.

Would that mean $\Bbb E[\mathbf{A + B}] = \Bbb E[X+Y]$?

Now in the trivial case of $n=1$, then this expectation might be true since a random vector of dimension 1 would be just a number. But what about for 2D basis vectors.

Is there a way such that you can have basis vectors like $(a_1, 0)$ and $(0,b_2)$ such that you can add them and get $(a_1,b_2)$?

Would this expectation still hold? No right?

I would think not because in the case of $X + Y$ both are numbers from the same dimension whereas for $(a_1, 0)$ and $(0,b_2)$, they are different dimensions.

Comment: A 1-d vector is just a number, so yes it's the same thing.

Comment: I don't understand your question but the expectation of a random vector is itself a vector whereas the expectation of random variable is a number. So the equality does not make any sense for $n >1$

Comment: That was what I was asking. That’s the answer I wanted to confirm. thanks